# How can I change the src in this html tag.I want to change src to some thing else

Tags: javascript, html

```
<div class="logo">
  <a href="somelink.com">
     <img src="someimage.png">
   </a>
 </div>
```

I want to change the src,how can I chage this src by using documents.getElementsByClassName.

Answer (score 1):

You can not use `getElementsByClassName` because you don't have any classes associated with it.

You could however use a `querySelector` and get the class of the div and find the child that way. So with this html:

```
<div class="logo">
 <a href="somelink.com">
    <img src="someimage.png">
  </a>
</div>
```

We can then use:

```
let img = document.querySelector('.logo img')
img.src = '/path/to/new/image.png'
```

- `.logo` this is the class to find
- `img` this is the child element of `.logo`

  - It doesn't have to be a direct child since there was no `>`

Once we have gotten that image we then set the new `src` to something else and the browser will automatically load the new image (assuming it exists).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
document.getElementsByClassName('img_ad')[0].src ='your source'
```

and add 'img_ad' class in the img element

```
<div class="logo">
  <a href="somelink.com">
     <img class="img_ad" src="someimage.png">
   </a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give the `img` tag an id and use:

```
document.getElementById("someid").src= "path/to/src";
```

or:

```
document.querySelector("#someid").src = "path/to/src";
```

Answer (score 0):

Add an ID to the `<img>` (Example: `id="myImage"`) and in JavaScript use the following:

```
document.getElementById("myImage").src = "newImage.png";
```